# django create row on user creation

Tags: python, django

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    student_rank = models.OneToOneField(
        StudentRankSignoff, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username`
```

When a Student signs up, i want to have the StudentRankSignoff table contain a blank row.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you heard about about django signals?

Comment: you need to create StudentRankSignoff in the views where you create the Student. can you show me view.py and StudentRankSignoff model?